# Is there a multiple integrator in Python providing both variable integration limits (like scipy) and high precision (like mpmath)?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, mpmath

I can use scipy quad and nquad for a quadruple integration involving variable integration limits. The problem is that the default precision used raises an Error when the tolerance requested cannot be achieved. With mpmath integrator, I can define any arbitrary precision with setting mp.dps = arbitrary, but I can't see if and how the limits can become variable like with nquad. Mpmath also provides a very fast execution with Gauss-Legendre method in quadgl, which is highly desirable, because my function is smooth, but takes an exorbitant amount of time with scipy to complete four integrations. Please help.
The below is only a simple function that fails my goal:

```
from datetime import datetime
import scipy
from scipy.special import jn, jn_zeros
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpmath import *
from mpmath import mp
from numpy import *
from scipy.optimize import *

# Set the precision
mp.dps = 15#; mp.pretty = True

# Setup shortcuts, so we can just write exp() instead of mp.exp(), etc.
F = mp.mpf
exp = mp.exp
sin = mp.sin
cos = mp.cos
asin = mp.asin
acos = mp.acos
sqrt = mp.sqrt
pi = mp.pi
tan = mp.tan

start = datetime.now()
print(start)

#optionsy={'limit':100, 'epsabs':1.49e-1, 'epsrel':1.49e-01}
#optionsx={'limit':100, 'epsabs':1.49e-1, 'epsrel':1.49e-01}

def f(x,y,z):
    return 2*sqrt(1-x**2) + y**2.0 + z

def rangex(y,z):
    return [-1,1]

def rangey(z):
    return [1,2]

def rangez():
    return [2,3]


def result():
    return quadgl(f, rangex, rangey, rangez)

"""
#The below works:

def result():
    return quadgl(f, [-1,1], [1,2], [2,3])
"""

print(result())

end = datetime.now()
print(end-start)
```

Comment: Aren't you supposed to split integrals recursively? From http://mpmath.org/doc/current/calculus/integration.html, look at the text and example "For nonrectangular areas, one can call quad() recursively."

Comment: Thanks and yes, I can recursively do up to three integrations with variable limits and arbitrary precision using mpmath. Then I could do my fourth integral (innermost) using scipy, but the error from the default precision will propagate to the outer three integrals.

Comment: Well, looks like you figured out how to deal with arbitrary limits. You could put your own answer. What I would suggest is to ask another question with your new code and be specific with precision loss. Don't try to ask several questions at once. I'll take a look at it

Comment: @Severin Thanks again. However, I did not manage to insert a "fourth" innermost scipy integral yet without errors. Even this would not be an improvement over the use of a quadruple scipy integration. In addition, mpmath takes very long time even with simple functions over a triple integration. My actual physical parameter at the output is expected to vary less than e-12 in relative terms. I suppose that the inside integrals should provide much better precision than this. At the limit, it takes many days, unless I drastically decrease the relative tolerance. Real problem.

Comment: I don't know if we can set epsabs and epsrel with mpmath. Ideally, we need this option together with increased precision in scipy and/or mpmath.Execution time is the last hurdle.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a simple example of how I can do only triple integration with mpmath. This does not address high precision with four integrations. In any case, execution time is even a bigger problem. Any help welcome.

```
from datetime import datetime
import scipy
import numpy as np
from mpmath import *
from mpmath import mp
from numpy import *

# Set the precision
mp.dps = 20#; mp.pretty = True

# Setup shortcuts, so we can just write exp() instead of mp.exp(), etc.
F = mp.mpf
exp = mp.exp
sin = mp.sin
cos = mp.cos
asin = mp.asin
acos = mp.acos
sqrt = mp.sqrt
pi = mp.pi
tan = mp.tan

start = datetime.now()
print('start: ',start)

def f3():
    def f2(x):
        def f1(x,y):
            def f(x,y,z):
                return 1.0 + x*y + y**2.0 + 3.0*z
            return quadgl(f, [-1.0, 1], [1.2*x, 1.0], [y/4, x**2.0])
        return quadgl(f1, [-1, 1.0], [1.2*x, 1.0])
    return quadgl(f2, [-1.0, 1.0])

print('result =', f3())

end = datetime.now()
print('duration in mins:',end-start)

#start:  2020-08-19 17:05:06.984375
#result = 5.0122222222222221749
#duration: 0:01:35.275956
```

Furthermore, an attempt to combine one (first) scipy integration followed by a triple mpmath integrator does not seem to produce any output for more than 24 hours even with a simplest function. What is wrong with the following code?

```
from datetime import datetime
import scipy
import numpy as np
from mpmath import *
from mpmath import mp
from numpy import *

from scipy import integrate

# Set the precision
mp.dps = 15#; mp.pretty = True

# Setup shortcuts, so we can just write exp() instead of mp.exp(), etc.
F = mp.mpf
exp = mp.exp
sin = mp.sin
cos = mp.cos
asin = mp.asin
acos = mp.acos
sqrt = mp.sqrt
pi = mp.pi
tan = mp.tan

start = datetime.now()
print('start: ',start)

#Function to be integrated
def f(x,y,z,w):
    return 1.0 + x + y + z + w 
    
#Scipy integration:FIRST INTEGRAL
def f0(x,y,z):
    return integrate.quad(f, -20, 10, args=(x,y,z), epsabs=1.49e-12, epsrel=1.4e-8)[0]


#Mpmath integrator of function f0(x,y,z): THREE OUTER INTEGRALS
def f3():
    def f2(x):
        def f1(x,y):
            return quadgl(f0, [-1.0, 1], [-2, x], [-10, y])
        return quadgl(f1, [-1, 1.0], [-2, x])
    return quadgl(f2, [-1.0, 1.0])

print('result =', f3())

end = datetime.now()
print('duration:', end-start)
```

Below is the full code, for which the original question was raised. It contains the use of scipy to carry out four integrations:

```
# Imports
from datetime import datetime
import scipy.integrate as si
import scipy
from scipy.special import jn, jn_zeros
from scipy.integrate import quad
from scipy.integrate import nquad
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import fixed_quad
from scipy.integrate import quadrature
from mpmath import mp

from numpy import *
from scipy.optimize import *

# Set the precision
mp.dps = 30

# Setup shortcuts, so we can just write exp() instead of mp.exp(), etc.
F = mp.mpf
exp = mp.exp
sin = mp.sin
cos = mp.cos
asin = mp.asin
acos = mp.acos
sqrt = mp.sqrt
pi = mp.pi
tan = mp.tan

start = datetime.now()
print(start)

R1 = F(6.37100000000000e6)
k1 = F(8.56677817058932e-8)
R2 = F(1.0)
k2 = F(5.45789437248245e-01)
r = F(12742000.0)

#Replace computed initial constants with values presuming is is faster, like below:
#a2 = R2/r
#print(a2) 
a2 = F(0.0000000784806152880238581070475592529)

def u1(phi2):
    return r*cos(phi2)-r*sqrt(a2**2.0-(sin(phi2))**2.0)
def u2(phi2):
    return r*cos(phi2)+r*sqrt(a2**2.0-(sin(phi2))**2.0)

def om(u,phi2):
    return u-r*cos(phi2)
def mp2(phi2):
    return r*sin(phi2)

def a1(u):
    return R1/u

optionsx={'limit':100, 'epsabs':1.49e-14, 'epsrel':1.49e-11}
optionsy={'limit':100, 'epsabs':1.49e-14, 'epsrel':1.49e-10}

#---- in direction u
def a1b1_u(x,y,u):
    return 2.0*u*sqrt(a1(u)**2.0-(sin(y))**2.0)

def oa2_u(x,y,u,phi2):
    return (mp2(phi2)*sin(y)*cos(x)+om(u,phi2)*cos(y) 
                    - sqrt((mp2(phi2)*sin(y)*cos(x)+om(u,phi2)*(cos(y)))**2.0 
                           + R2**2.0-om(u,phi2)**2.0-mp2(phi2)**2.0))

def ob2_u(x,y,u,phi2):
    return (mp2(phi2)*sin(y)*cos(x)+om(u,phi2)*cos(y) 
                    + sqrt((mp2(phi2)*sin(y)*cos(x)+om(u,phi2)*(cos(y)))**2.0 
                           + R2**2.0-om(u,phi2)**2.0-mp2(phi2)**2.0))

def func1_u(x,y,u,phi2):
    return (-exp(-k1*a1b1_u(x,y,u)-k2*ob2_u(x,y,u,phi2))+exp(+k2*oa2_u(x,y,u,phi2)))*sin(y)*cos(y)
 
#--------joint_coaxial integration: u1
def fg_u1(u,phi2):
    return nquad(func1_u, [[-pi, pi], [0, asin(a1(u))]], args=(u,phi2), opts=[optionsx,optionsy])[0]

#Constants to be used for normalization at the end or in the interim inegrals if this helps adjust values for speed of execution
piA1 = pi*(R1**2.0-1.0/(2.0*k1**2.0)+exp(-2.0*k1*R1)*(2.0*k1*R1+1.0)/(2.0*k1**2.0))
piA2 = pi*(R2**2.0-1.0/(2.0*k2**2.0)+exp(-2.0*k2*R2)*(2.0*k2*R2+1.0)/(2.0*k2**2.0))

#----THIRD integral of u1
def third_u1(u,phi2):
    return fg_u1(u,phi2)*u**2.0
def third_u1_I(phi2):
    return quad(third_u1, u1(phi2), u2(phi2), args = (phi2), epsabs=1.49e-20, epsrel=1.49e-09)[0]
    
#----FOURTH integral of u1
def fourth_u1(phi2):
    return third_u1_I(phi2)*sin(phi2)*cos(phi2)
def force_u1():
    return quad(fourth_u1, 0.0, asin(a2), args = (), epsabs=1.49e-20, epsrel=1.49e-08)[0]


force_u1 = force_u1()*r**2.0*2.0*pi*k2/piA1/piA2

print('r = ', r, 'force_u1 =', force_u1)

end = datetime.now()
print(end)

args = {
            'p':r,
            'q':force_u1,
            'r':start,
            's':end
        }   

#to txt file
f=open('Sphere-test-force-u-joint.txt', 'a')

f.write('\n{p},{q},{r},{s}'.format(**args))
#f.flush()
f.close()
```

I am interested in setting the epsrel sufficiently low, depending on the case. The epsabs is generally unknown apriori, so I understand that I should make it very low to avoid it taking hold of the output, in which case it introduces an computational articact. When I make it lower, an Error warning is raised that the round-off errors are significant and the total error may be underestimated for the desired tolerance to be achieved.

Comment: Bumped. Could you add code for full expression (all 4 integrals) to compute?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let me put something in answer, hard to put code in the comments

Simple optimization with MP math is to follow simple rules:

1. y<sup>2.0</sup> is VERY expensive (log, exp, ...), replace with y*y
2. y<sup>2</sup> is still expensive, replace with y*y
3. multiplication is a lot more expensive than summation, replace x*y + y**2.0 with (x+y)*y
4. Division is more expensive than multiplication, replace y/4 with 0.25*y

Code, Win 10 x64, Python 3.8

```
def f3():
    def f2(x):
        def f1(x,y):
            def f(x,y,z):
                return 1.0 + (x+y)*y + 3.0*z
            return mpmath.quadgl(f, [-1.0, 1], [1.2*x, 1.0], [0.25*y, x*x])
        return mpmath.quadgl(f1, [-1, 1.0], [1.2*x, 1.0])
    return mpmath.quadgl(f2, [-1.0, 1.0])
```

on my computer went from 12.9 sec to 10.6 sec, about 20% off

Comment: Thought inappropriate to engage community with full code. Very happy to do so below. I use other computer with: "x64based PC, MS Windows 7 Home Premium, Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) 3612QM CPU @2.10 GHz up to 3.0 GHz with turbo boost, 4-Core, 8-Logical Processors, 8 GB RAM". Have tried to run parallel multi-core instances where I have summed terms. Not sure if this helps when there is subtraction of terms, unsure about how precision and end result is affected by splitting code. Your help is extremely appreciated.

Comment: I have experienced big errors introduced when I use integers and not decimal expressions (like 2 instead of 2.0), especially in the exponents.

Comment: @gerryD I'll take a look and see what I could do

Answer (score 0):

Whilst the question is not about speed, the latter is intimately connected with making practical the execution of a quadruple integration prior to the inquiry about precision and tolerance. To test the speed, I set (increased) all four epsrel=1e-02, which reduced the time of the original code down to 2:14 (hours). Then I simplified powers per Severin and implemented some [memoization](https://pypi.org/project/memoization/). These reduced the time cumulatively down to 1:29 (hours). The edited lines of the code are provided here:

```
from memoization import cached

@cached(ttl=10)
def u1(phi2):
    return r*cos(phi2)-r*sqrt(a2*a2-sin(phi2)*sin(phi2))
@cached(ttl=10)
def u2(phi2):
    return r*cos(phi2)+r*sqrt(a2*a2-sin(phi2)*sin(phi2))
@cached(ttl=10)
def om(u,phi2):
    return u-r*cos(phi2)
@cached(ttl=10)
def mp2(phi2):
    return r*sin(phi2)
@cached(ttl=10)
def a1(u):
    return R1/u

optionsx={'limit':100, 'epsabs':1.49e-14, 'epsrel':1.49e-02}
optionsy={'limit':100, 'epsabs':1.49e-14, 'epsrel':1.49e-02}

def a1b1_u(x,y,u):
    return 2.0*u*sqrt(a1(u)*a1(u)-sin(y)*sin(y))

def oa2_u(x,y,u,phi2):
    return (mp2(phi2)*sin(y)*cos(x)+om(u,phi2)*cos(y) 
                    - sqrt((mp2(phi2)*sin(y)*cos(x)+om(u,phi2)*(cos(y)))**2.0 
                           + 1.0-om(u,phi2)*om(u,phi2)-mp2(phi2)*mp2(phi2)))

def ob2_u(x,y,u,phi2):
    return (mp2(phi2)*sin(y)*cos(x)+om(u,phi2)*cos(y) 
                    + sqrt((mp2(phi2)*sin(y)*cos(x)+om(u,phi2)*(cos(y)))**2.0 
                           + 1.0-om(u,phi2)*om(u,phi2)-mp2(phi2)*mp2(phi2)))

def third_u1(u,phi2):
    return fg_u1(u,phi2)*u*u

def third_u1_I(phi2):
    return quad(third_u1, u1(phi2), u2(phi2), args = (phi2), epsabs=1.49e-20, epsrel=1.49e-02)[0]
    
def force_u1():
    return quad(fourth_u1, 0.0, asin(a2), args = (), epsabs=1.49e-20, epsrel=1.49e-02)[0]
```

However, the output is an artifact caused by the inadequate tolerance introduced. I can progressively set the epsrel to lower values and see if the result converges to a realistic value in realistic time with the available scipy precision. Hope this illustrates the original question much better.

Comment: IMPORTANT: In a follow-up of progressively increasing the epsrel, I have reproduced the "IntegrationWarning: The occurrence of roundoff error is detected, which prevents the requested tolerance from being achieved. The error may be underestimated". This occurs with epsrel=1.49e-03, 1.49e-06, 1.49e-03, 1.49e-05 from the innermost to the outermost integrals, whilst prior setting epsrel=1.49e-03, 1.49e-05, 1.49e-03, 1.49e-05 completed normally after  17:45 (hours). The failed run was started overnight and no record of occurrence time is made. @Severin

Comment: Note: The failing test was repeated and the IntegrationWarning was raised after about 50 mins. It seems that Scipy progresses well, but its default precision needs to be user controlled. Is it possible to do that? (per original question)